# Enable drag and drop upload in div container

Tags: php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm sure there are a couple of questions similar to this one out there but I had no idea what to search for.

What I'm looking for is a way to enable drag and drop into a div on my website. Currently when I drop a file into the page (I'm using Chrome) it displays the file (a file:// url) which is not what I want. If there's a way to do this without using any plugins I'd be more then happy. It should support multiple files.

This is what my div-css looks like:

```
#dnd {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

And here're my jQuery binds for the drag:

```
function processFileUpload(droppedFiles)
{
    var uploadFormData = new FormData($("#dnd")[0]); 
    if(droppedFiles.length > 0)
    {
        for(f = 0; f < droppedFiles.length; f++)
        {
            uploadFormData.append("upload[]",droppedFiles[f]);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : "index.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : uploadFormData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false
    });
}

$("#dnd").bind("dragenter", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#8c8c8c");
    return false;
});

$("#dnd").bind("dragleave", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#c9c9c9");
    return false;
});

$("#dnd").bind("drop", function(e) {
    files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    processFileUpload(files);
    return false;
});
```

Appreciate all comments and answers. Thank you!

Comment: how about: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for your comment but I've got my own upload-script in PHP working fine (having a button on the same page as the drag and drop). I just need to figure out how to make so that the div allow dragging and dropping.

Comment: Try adding `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.preventDefault();` to your *drop* callback.

Comment: @MetodMedja Didn't do anything. Thanks for your comment though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the *dragover* event must be canceled for the *drop* event to fire.
To fix it just add this:

```
$("#dnd").bind('dragover', function() {
    return false;
});
```

Here's a working example I made by following your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hmf4T/
You can see the files in the console output.

Comment: The fiddle works as you said but it's not working after i've implemented it onto my website. Have I missed something? http://bonecountyroleplay.com/switchbox/

Comment: Just include jQuery before your script and change `function upload` to `function processFileUpload`.

Comment: Woops, thank you. Although it still brings me to the file's file:// url.

Comment: Ok I copied your code and found a solution. On line 32 change `if(file.length > 0)` to `if(files.length > 0)` (sorry, my bad) and right after `$('#dnd').bind('drop', function() {` add `event.preventDefault();`. `return false;` won't cut it this time.

Comment: Working! Thank you soo much for your help. Really appreciate it.